# Send JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json, instagram-api

I want to follow with Instagram API in PHP, but it shows an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sendPostData() in /storage/h11/133/1908133/public_html/index.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /storage/h11/133/1908133/public_html/index.php on line 13
```

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>indexer</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$access = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$user_id = 'xxxxxxxx';
$url= 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$user_id.'/relationship?access_token='.$access;
$data = 'action=follow';
$resultObj = json_decode(sendPostData($url,$data));
print_r($resultObj);
?>
```

Comment: There is no `sendPostData` function in your scope. There is no build-in function of such name.

Comment: I think you have to use curl in php for rest api.

Comment: howi can curl in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to get or to modify first be clear about it.
if you want to retrieve it needs a GET request
- Get information about a relationship to another user.

```
  $request_uri =  https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/relationship?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

and if you want to modify something
- Modify the relationship between the current user and the target user.

```
   $request_uri = https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/relationship?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

about curl request

```
$request_uri = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/relationship';

$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $request_uri,
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
        'access_token' => ACCESS-TOKEN,
    )
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

Hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: @snip1377 glad, it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$resultObj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url,$data));
```

Hope it will work

Comment: i try but we have a warning  :                                 Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/xxxxxxxx/relationship?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /storage/ssd4/848/1911848/public_html/index.php on line 6
salam

Comment: print $resulobj using print_r($resultObj);

and another thing try to remove json_decode then see result

Comment: I use curl.tnx about helping